# View activity list of google plus on android

Tags: android, android-activity, google-plus

I'm following the documentation of google plus list and I am using this code:

```
Plus.Activities.List listActivities = plus.activities().list("me", "public");
listActivities.setMaxResults(5L);

// Execute the request for the first page
ActivityFeed activityFeed = listActivities.execute();

// Unwrap the request and extract the pieces we want
List<Activity> activities = activityFeed.getItems();

// Loop through until we arrive at an empty page
while (activities != null) {
    for (Activity activity : activities) {
        System.out.println("ID " + activity.getId() + " Content: " +
            activity.getObject().getContent());
}

// We will know we are on the last page when the next page token is null.
// If this is the case, break.
if (activityFeed.getNextPageToken() == null) {
    break;
}

// Prepare to request the next page of activities
listActivities.setPageToken(activityFeed.getNextPageToken());

// Execute and process the next page request
activityFeed = listActivities.execute();
activities = activityFeed.getItems();
```

This does not work because I have to create a client object. I tried more example but I do not understand how to do. Now:
How do I create a client object?
Where do I insert this client object?
I've seen a lot of answers but none work. You can Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment that proceeded that code sample asked you to take a look at the [Google+ Java quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java), see the [source file in question](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java/blob/master/src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/Signin.java) for how to set up your credentials and Plus client. You'll also need to authorize your request, that sample project shows how to use Google+ Sign-In to authorize the user to get an access token. You must have an authorized user to search with `"me"`.

This sample is Java code using the Google Java API client library, the Android SDK doesn't include the client library by default, so you'd need to import that into your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at this project : [google API calendar](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html)

It works exactly like that with the G+ API.